# SELECT and update the row in DataTable

Tags: c#

I have a following SQL statement and would like to update Database table if row found.

```
string sql = "Select A.CNum FROM TABLEA A, TABLEB B WHERE A.CID= B.CID AND A.CNum is NULL AND CID=@cID"

DataTable dt = querySql(sql, params);

                if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    // I would like to update CNum from TableA
                }
```

What is the best method to update the row from SQL Statement?

Thank you..

Answer (score 2):

It should be possible to do this in one statement without round-tripping any data from the database and back:

`UPDATE
    TABLEA
SET
    CNum = newValueHere
FROM
    TABLEA A,
    INNER JOIN TABLEB B ON B.CID = A.CID
WHERE
    A.CNum is NULL
AND A.CID=@cID`

note I qualified the CID reference in the last line ( I think you'll get an error without this as it exists on both tables, and used an inner join to connect your tables. Note that newValueHere can be an expression of any of the columns in A or B.

Comment: Thanks Tom. I would like to return TRUE from this method if there is a row in the table. How would I know if there is a record in the table?

Answer (score 1):

Using the SQL from Tom's answer with the following C# will give you what you want.

```
using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conection)) 
{
    int rowsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `EXISTS` construct to do this in just one query.

```
string sql = "IF EXISTS(Select A.CNum FROM TABLEA A, TABLEB B WHERE A.CID= B.CID AND A.CNum is NULL AND CID=@cID) BEGIN ..... END"
```

Comment: Thank you. I am not using stored procedure. Is there anyway I can find if row has been updated?